# Как открыть индексацию только одной страницы сайта

Tags: seo, индексация, robots.txt

У меня сайт на этапе разработки. Хочу открыть индексацию страниц по мере их готовности. Сейчас сайт полностью закрыт от индексации.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разрешить индексацию только одной страницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавьте в конец директиву `Allow: *УРЛ вашей страницы*$`. Например, `Allow: /abc/$`

Comment: а если страница завернута в тег NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW, его просто нужно убрать в коде, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @user512643, да, крайне желательно это сделать, поскольку этот запрет поисковым роботом будет встречен последним, а значит действующим

Comment: если я хочу разрешить индексацию главной страницы, то выглядит это так: Allow: /$ или я что-то путаю?

Comment: @user512643 1. Да; 2. `Allow: /ru/$`

PS: Советую использовать инструмент проверки файла роботс в вебмастере поисковика на букву Я, он вам поможет